# Is this a good way to extract the name of a script?

Tags: perl, filenames

My situation is this: I want a Perl script to say its own name. I tried

```
print "$0\n";
```

which is a good solution if you are working in the same directory were the script is. I find this solution

```
use strict;
use warnings;
$0 =~ /([\w\.\-\_]+)$/;
my $this = $1;
print "my name is $this\n";
```

Is it a good solution?

Comment: Notice name is not well defined, when the script is still running, the file name on the filesystem can be changed, the mentioned script simply print argv[0] of the current process (which technically can also be written to). Also, the word "good" is not well defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can be sure that a file name will never have a `/`. Therefore, it's enough to do:

```
$0=~/([^\/]+)$/;
my $this = $1;
print "my name is $this\n";
```

Anything else (except `\0`) is fair game in a file name. So your approach would have missed a crazy filename like this:

```
th&is%sc(ip)tHas
      a^really#weird"+Name=!
```

And yes, you can create a file with that name:

```
$ touch 'th&is%sc(ip)tHas'$'\n'$'\t''a^really#weird"+Name=!'
$ ls -l *Nam*
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Jul  5 16:00 'th&is%sc(ip)tHas'$'\n\t''a^really#weird"+Name=!'
```

But Perl can handle that. I saved the lines above with that horrible name and ran:

```
$ perl *Nam*
my name is th&is%sc(ip)tHas
    a^really#weird"+Name=!
```

Your original version would have failed with:

```
$ perl *Nam*
Use of uninitialized value $this in concatenation (.) or string at th&is%sc(ip)tHas
    a^really#weird"+Name=! line 7.
my name is
```

That's because `[\w\.\-\_]`<sup>1</sup> doesn't match any of the symbols (`&%()^#"+=!`) or the whitespace in the name.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>You don't need to escape most of those, by the way. Just use `[\w.\-_]`.</sub>

Comment: Oh yes, I supposed no such weird filenames. :)

Comment: @IndrjoDedej this is an extreme example, but your approach would also file on `name with spaces.pl` or `script:v1.pl` etc.

Comment: I was told filenames with spaces are dangerous. XD

Comment: @IndrjoDedej you were told right! :) But here, try running this on your system: `find / -mount -type f -printf '%f\n' | perl -ne 'print unless /^[\w_.\-]+$/'`. That should give you a multitude of "bad" file names.